# How to print several items at once

Tags: python, addition

```
print "i'm going to calculate minutes for you \n"

print "enter the amount of minutes for your introduction"
intro_minutes = int(raw_input('# '))

print "enter the amount of seconds for your introduction"
intro_seconds = int(raw_input('# ')) 

print "your introduction is "  (intro_seconds + (60 * intro_minutes)) " seconds long."
```

I'm creating this program to time a speech I have to deliver. The error I'm getting is:

```
File "speech.py", line 9
    print "your introduction is " (intro_seconds + (60 * intro_minutes)) " seconds long.)

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution is to concatenate the strings you wish to print:

```
print "your introduction is " + str(intro_seconds + (60 * intro_minutes)) + " seconds long."
```

Note the additional call to `str()` to convert your number into a string, as Python will error if you try to add a number to a string (as it's not clear what you want).

This kind of concatenation is a little ugly though, so you might want to use string formatting instead:

```
print "your introduction is {0} seconds long.".format(intro_seconds + (60 * intro_minutes))
```

Comment: I'm not sure `need to concatenate` is the correct wording... Just getting the syntax right for print would work without having to create a new string

Comment: @JonClements That's true, it's definitely a valid way of doing it - I just tend to not do it that way myself, and so didn't think of it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to somehow concatenate the different pieces of what you want to print. The easiest way to do that in your case is to add a comma:

```
print "your introduction is",  (intro_seconds + (60 * intro_minutes)), "seconds long."
```

Of course, the more "classical" way to do that is to do string concatentation:

```
print "your introduction is " + str(intro_seconds + (60 * intro_minutes)) + " seconds long."
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I opted for the former option.

Comment: +1, Passing multiple arguments (well, not quite in 2.x as it's not a function, but you get what I mean), is a valid way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

you need to conactenate the strings:

```
print "your introduction is " + str(intro_seconds + (60 * intro_minutes)) + " seconds long."
```

or:

```
print "your introduction is %d seconds long." % (intro_seconds + (60 * intro_minutes))
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use commas to separate the values in print :

```
print "your introduction is ", (intro_seconds + (60 * intro_minutes)), " seconds long."
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print "your introduction is %s seconds long" % (intro_seconds + (60 * intro_minutes))
```